# Which definition of 'vest' applies in 'vested interest'?

Tags: meaning, legalese

Which definition at http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vest_2 applies to http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vested%20interest? I want to dredge below this term, and ask not about the Merriam Webster dictionary that I already apprehend.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase [vested interest](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vested-interest) has a different meaning in common usage than the individual words. Definition of vested interest noun from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary: *"a personal reason for wanting something to happen, especially because you get some advantage from it"*. For example, *"She has a vested interest in the proposed ban on plastic bags because she owns a business that sells canvas shopping bags."*

The meaning probably evolved from the legal definition ["A right or title, as to present or future possession of an estate, that can be conveyed to another."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vested+interest) If you held a vested interest in a property, you would have a personal interest in increasing or maintaining the value of the property, so that your title to it is valuable.

Comment: Sounds a lot like being *invested* in something, no? I think the common meaning of *vested* is the same, not different from, the use of *vested* in *vested interest*. When you *vest* in a company you become involved with it, part of it. You have a vested interest in it.

Comment: The meanings are similar, but different unless you are talking specifically about the legal definition. There is a reason that dictionaries like OALD list "vested interest" as a phrase distinct from vest or invest, and that you will only find "vested right" defined in legal dictionaries. As a phrase, "vested interest" has come to mean more than the sum of its parts.